# Webview zoom out programmatically

Tags: android, android-webview

I have a webview displaying a map as an svg object. Users can zoom in and out using pinch controls. I also have a button outside of webview that should animate zooming out to default zoom level.

I'm unable to find a way to write a zoom out javascript code that actually works on webview.

Comment: Vote my answer below. Set default zoom out = **webview.setInitialScale(-1);**

Answer (score 9, accepted):

you can handle zoom percent like this:

```
mWebView.setInitialScale(ZOOM_LEVEL);
```

which ZOOM_LEVEL is zoom percentage number

Comment: I was blind to the fact that it actually preforms the animation. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use pinch zoom settings go with:-

***mWebView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);***

[WebViewSettings](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebSettings.html)

Answer (score 1):

You can **Zoom-In** into a web page utilizing the following method
`webview.zoomIn()`;

Answer (score 0):

Set default zoom out = **webview.setInitialScale(-1);**